# Slow tableView reload with Yelp API iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am playing around with Yelp's API. I have managed to create a small app that allows the user to input a 'term' and 'location', and a tableView containing 5 businesses appear. However, it takes about 30 seconds to a minute for the data to appear on the tableview after clicking search. If I log out the JSONresponse, the data is in my NSArrray in a second, but still doesn't appear in the tableView. 
Sometimes, the businesses won't appear at all.

The code I use to search.

```
    - (IBAction)searchButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    YPAPISample *YPAPI = [[YPAPISample alloc]init];

    NSString *term = self.termTextField.text;
    NSString *location = self.locationTextField.text;

    dispatch_group_t requestGroup = dispatch_group_create();

    dispatch_group_enter(requestGroup);

    [YPAPI queryBusinessesForTerm:term location:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *jsonResponse, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {

            self.businessInfoArray = jsonResponse;
            NSLog(@"%lu",[businessInfoArray count]);
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
        else NSLog(@"%@", error);

        dispatch_group_leave(requestGroup);
    }];


        dispatch_group_wait(requestGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER); // This avoids the program exiting before all our asynchronous callbacks have been made.


}
```

Comment: Do you load a large size of images? Can you show us the part where you pull the information from?

Comment: Please create a [sample of code that demonstrates the problem and can be included inline here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Links to your entire project [do not make for an acceptable SO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89309/).

Comment: No images are being loaded, I'm just taking the name of the business from the dictionary. @Bejibun

Comment: Never do UI updates on a background thread.

Comment: Is the dispatch making it a background thread? I got rid of that and it still takes the same amount of time to update  @rmaddy

Comment: The completion handler is called on a background thread. It's easy to verify. Set a breakpoint and see what thread it is.

Answer (score 0):

you have to reload your table data with using performselector on main thread you can easily got a data on time 
remove this dispatch group from your code
e.g

-

```
 (void)queryTopBusinessInfoForTerm:(NSString *)term location:(NSString *)location category:(NSString *)category completionHandler:(void (^)(NSDictionary *topBusinessJSON, NSError *error))completionHandler
{

    NSLog(@"Querying the Search API with term \'%@\' and location \'%@' and category '%@'", term, location,category);


    NSURLRequest *searchRequest = [self _searchRequestWithTerm:term location:location category:category];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:searchRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;

        if (!error && httpResponse.statusCode == 200)
        {

            NSDictionary *searchResponseJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
            NSArray *businessArray = searchResponseJSON[@"businesses"];

            if ([businessArray count] > 0)
            {

                NSLog(@"total businesses==>%@",[searchResponseJSON valueForKey:@"total"]);

                lblresults.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[searchResponseJSON valueForKey:@"total"]];

                 hotelListArray = [businessArray mutableCopy];
                allObjectArray = [businessArray mutableCopy];
                 self.tableHotels.hidden = NO;

                [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(ReloadTableData:) withObject:hotelListArray waitUntilDone:YES];
            }
            else
            {
                completionHandler(nil, error); // No business was found

            }
        }
        else
        {
            completionHandler(nil, error); // An error happened or the HTTP response is not a 200 OK

        }
    }] resume];
```